# Scale and Save Images (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape')

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scale, attributeerror

I'm trying to scale and save a thousand images to a directory.

I succeeded to resize images. However, errors occur while saving.

Code is below. Help me pls.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

def scaling_shirink(addr):
    img = cv2.imread(addr)
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    shrink = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow('Shrink', shrink)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

count = 0
IMAGE_DIR_BASE = 'C:/ClassShared\Data/CM_ML_IMG_181011/CASE_01/FPS_10_PNG'
image_file_list = os.listdir(IMAGE_DIR_BASE)
for file_name in image_file_list:
    image = scaling_shirink(IMAGE_DIR_BASE + '/' + file_name)
    cv2.imwrite('C:/ClassShared\Data/CM_ML_IMG_181011/CASE_01/34_sdetect_db1/' + '_' + "%04d" % (count) + '.png', image)
    count = count + 1
```

Error messages are as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/TS_S/Scailing.py", line 19, in <module>
    image = scaling_shirink(IMAGE_DIR_BASE + '/' + file_name)
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/TS_S/Scailing.py", line 8, in scaling_shirink
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I don't understand why it says 
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: `cv2.imread(addr)` returned `None`.  Are you sure `addr` is correct?  Are there any non-image files in that directory?

Comment: sure its correct and if I run without for statement, then it run well.

Comment: The above code is a little wrong, and the return of the scaling_shirink function is shirink.

Comment: If it's wrong, then fix it.  We can't help if you don't show us the real code.

Comment: I solved this porblem haha it was simple thing! thx for answering John :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Check if the image path is correct and if it its in fact a image with the formats accepted by Opencv. Because if your path is wrong the `img = cv2.imread(addr)` will return `None` and `height, width = img.shape[:2]` will throw an error

Also, your function scaling_shirink() is returning None.
To fix it, just change it to the function below:

```
def scaling_shirink(addr):
    img = cv2.imread(addr)
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    shrink = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow('Shrink', shrink)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    #this return was missing
    return shrink
```

That should work!

Comment: This is not the problem that is causing the error (although it is another problem for OP); `img.shape` is throwing the error before the `return` statement would even happen because the `imread()` function is returning `None`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds you are right! Altough the lack o return in the function is also a problem. Thanks for the tip